# Dont understand this phrase: "Seq is often used to provide a rich collection API to JavaScript Object."

Tags: immutable.js

In the docs for `SEQ` at https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Seq there appears this phrase: "**Seq is often used to provide a rich collection API to JavaScript Object.**" followed by this code example:

`Seq({ x: 0, y: 1, z: 2 }).map(v => v * 2).toObject();
// { x: 0, y: 2, z: 4 }`

This has no meaning to me. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.map` is a Method available on the array object which is used to iterate over the items and to which a function can be passed in that could transform the original array.

Similarly `.Seq` makes it possible to do the same with objects

Comment: So all they are saying is that you could use Seq on an object to get access to some things like map, before converting it back to an object? 

Weird. I'd probably just use a for in loop myself. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. No problem. You could use a for loop but this is more of a functional style of programming.